# Print the string between two brackets

Tags: perl, sed, grep

I have file with these lines

```
G8 = P(G1,G3)
G9 = P(G3,G4)
G12 = P(G2,G9)
G15 = P(G9,G5)
G16 = P(G8,G12)
G17 = P(G12,G15)
```

I need the output as

```
G1,G3
G3,G4
.....
```

How can I do it with sed/grep command or using perl?

Comment: What `grep`/`perl` commands have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/).*//' filename
```

Or more concisely:

```
sed 's/.*(//;s/)//' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nE 'say /\( (.+?) \)/x' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat your-file-name.txt | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1
```

You don't even need grep / sed!

Comment: It's necessary to help him understand the concept thaugh.. ;) Thanks anyways!

Comment: The concept of [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)?

Comment: Still...It does its job.

Comment: `cut` can take a filename as an argument. This does the same thing without the `cat`: `cut -d '(' -f2 filename | cut -d')' -f1`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}' file
G1,G3
G3,G4
G2,G9
G9,G5
G8,G12
G12,G15
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions using PERL

```
# Assuming a relation between the Char letter
$str =~ s/(G)\d+?\ *?=\ P\((\1\d+?,\ *?\1\d+?)\)/$2/;

# A greedy solution. Just capturing the content of the paranthesis.
$str =~ s/.*?\((.*?)\).*?/$1/;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ruby

```
# ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/\((.*)\)/)' file
G1,G3
G3,G4
G2,G9
G9,G5
G8,G12
G12,G15
```